# Select 4 Rows based on MAX value as Slideshow

Tags: php, pdo, max

I have this columns in my table "sales":

[image]

in column **jml_terjual**, I want to pick 4 highest number of sales (7,9,11 and 12). After that, I want them to show in slideshow as best-seller products.

```
$qSite="SELECT MAX(jml_terjual) AS max FROM sales ORDER BY id LIMIT 4,0";
$uQue = $acn->prepare ($qSite);
$uQue->execute();
$resQ = $uQue->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($resQ>0 || !$resQ>0){
?>

<?php
slide here
}
?>
```

But I just get one slide appears. From this illustration, how can I show 4 images in column photo_produk as best-seller product in slideshow.

I use bootstrap slides as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="banner" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <a href="" title="" target="_top"><img src="????" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="" title="" target="_top"><img src="????" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="" title="" target="_top"><img src="????" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="" title="" target="_top"><img src="????" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code for your slider, then i can help you out. It's hard without the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.So if you want to show four values, change query

```
SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY jml_terjual DESC LIMIT 4
```

**Updated:**

```
<?php
$qry = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY jml_terjual DESC LIMIT 4,0");
$qry->execute();
$varQ = $qry->fetchAll();
foreach ($varQ as $data) {
   $imgslide=$data['photo_produk'];
...etc
   }
?>
```

Then fetch the result using loop